# What does it mean when someone assign me an issue on GitHub?

Tags: github, assign

I have submitted a pull request to an issue. Afterwards, I received an email informing me that I was being assigned to that particular issue. What does this mean and what am I supposed to do? Should I continue to improvise that issue??

Comment: Did you ask the person who assigned the issue to you?

Comment: This is highly dependent on the Repository/Project you are contributing to there is not a general answer to that.

Comment: @StephenNewell nope but I received a notification from GitHub informing me that the pull request was merged and closed.

Comment: @Lalaluka I see. Thanks for letting me know about this!

Answer (score 0):

These are the general steps you need to take

- read carefully your email, see what its title and content is
- click on the View on GitHub link, so the page will be opened
- look for comments and history on the page
- look for further commits that may have been pushed to this branch, if you are not the author, then you will probably need to look into them
- if still unclear, reread your code and see what may be the problem
- if still unclear, ask the person who assigned it back

Comment: Thanks for the guide. I will ask the person who assigned me the issue to get a clearer answer!

Comment: @MeiKei you are welcome. I think this approach should guide you to finding out what you should do. If so, then you might consider accepting this answer as the correct one.